Window Size Changes Depending on Search Results
The size of my window changes depending on how many hits my search results yield.

Here is what happens after I search.

As you can see, the width of the window greatly decreases based on the number of hits that my search yields. I want the width of my window (and therefore the location and width of other aspects of my site) to remain the same, regardless of the number of hits.
Any idea what might be causing this? HTML and CSS below.
tile.css
/* Tile styles */

.tile {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white; /* Ensure a consistent background color */
    width: 150px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add some spacing between tiles */
}

.tile img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.tile .details {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer; /* Ensure the cursor is a pointer */
}

.tile .details p {
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
}

/* Styles for selected tiles */
.tile.selected {
    border: 2px solid #007bff;
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}

/* Ensure tile-container takes up the full width */
.tile-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}

style.css
@import url('styles/reset.css');
@import url('styles/layout.css');
@import url('styles/components.css');
@import url('styles/search.css');
@import url('styles/tile.css');
@import url('styles/table.css');
@import url('styles/grid.css');
@import url('styles/file.css');
@import url('styles/actions-dropdown.css');
@import url('styles/account-dropdown.css');

/* Ensure the modal is hidden by default */
#uploadModal, #artModal {
    display: none;
}

.view-toggle {
    margin-left: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

index.html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gallery X - Upload Files</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header-bar">
        <div class="header-logo">T A S T E</div>
        <div class="header-account">
            <div class="account-dropdown">
                <i class="fas fa-user account-icon"></i>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">My Account</a>
                    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                    <a href="#">Orders</a>
                    <a href="#">Returns</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="gallery-name">Gallery X</div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Files</li>
                    <li>Packet</li>
                    <li>Trash</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Files</h1>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <button id="uploadButton" onclick="openModal()">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search-and-toggle-container">
                <div class="search-container">
                    <input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="searchTable()" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <div class="view-toggle">
                    <button class="grid-list-button" id="tableViewButton">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <span class="dots">
                                <i></i>
                                <i></i>
                                <i></i>
                                <i></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="lines">
                                <i></i>
                                <i></i>
                                <i></i>
                                <i></i>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tableView" class="view">
                <table id="artworkTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="checkbox-column"><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckbox" onclick="selectAll(this)"></th>
                            <th>Artist</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Year</th>
                            <th>Dimensions</th>
                            <th>Medium</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>File Size</th>
                            <th>Uploaded On</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Rows will be added here dynamically -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tileView" class="view" style="display: none;">
                <div class="tile-container" id="tileContainer">
                    <!-- Tiles will be added here dynamically -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions-container">
                <button class="actions-button" onclick="toggleActionsDropdown()">Actions <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <div id="actionsDropdown" class="actions-dropdown">
                    <a href="#" onclick="createPacket()">Create Packet</a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="deleteSelected()">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="uploadModal" class="modal" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
            <h2>Upload Art</h2>
            <p>Supported format: PDF</p>
            <div id="drop_zone_modal" class="drop-zone">
                <span class="drop-zone__prompt">Drag & drop your file here or</span>
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('file_input_modal').click();">Choose File</button>
                <input type="file" id="file_input_modal" name="pdf" hidden>
            </div>
            <p id="file_info_modal">Max File Size: 5MB</p>
            <div id="file_name_modal"></div>
            <button type="submit" onclick="uploadFile()">Upload File</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Art Modal -->
    <div id="artModal" class="modal" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" onclick="closeArtModal()">&times;</span>
            <img id="artModalImg" src="" alt="Artwork" style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px; object-fit: contain;">
            <h2 id="artModalTitle"></h2>
            <p><strong>Artist:</strong> <span id="artModalArtist"></span></p>
            <p><strong>Year:</strong> <span id="artModalYear"></span></p>
            <p><strong>Dimensions:</strong> <span id="artModalDimensions"></span></p>
            <p><strong>Medium:</strong> <span id="artModalMedium"></span></p>
            <p><strong>Price:</strong> <span id="artModalPrice"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>

I don't want the number of results to impact the width of my window.

.main { min-width: 100vw; }; Maybe giving main element a min-width will help.
